# Виндовый фтп, ошибка

Tags: windows, ftp

> ftp> ls    500 Illegal PORT command.    425 Use PORT or PASV first.

Пробую `put`, `send`, `ls` выдает такую ошибку. Куда копать подскажите.

Comment: Закрывайте вопрос, написал программку, закидывает и не парюсь)

Answer (score 2):

Портовый либо пассивный режим задать надо, однако! Пассивный проще. Попробуйте после соединения с ftp сервером, но перед приёмом/передачей файла, дать команду"quote PASV" (без кавычек). Ну или другой вариант - воспользоваться другим ftp клиентом, например Wget.

Comment: пробовал пасв, не помогает

Comment: Ну, можно конечно ещё remotehelp  в вендовом ftp попробовать, чтобы знать, какие команды удалённый сервак понимает, но это, скорее - для мазохистов! Под вендой проще Wget  поставить, или нечто подобное, чтобы пассивный режим включало!

Comment: wget только закачивает файлы (или я не прав?), а мне нужно отправлять)